# Form controls are not accessible in the code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

The controls like txtEmail and PanelSignUp are not accessible in the code behind.  I'm getting errors on these lines when I'm trying to build the website.

Mark up of my Acsx page control is as below

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="Articulate.userControls_emailSignUp" Codebehind="emailSignUp.ascx.vb" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"    TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:HiddenField ID="URL" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="siteID" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="siteName" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="siteURL" runat="server" />

 <a name="signUp"></a>
 <div class="signup">
 <asp:Panel ID="PanelSignUp" runat="server">

  <div class="grid_8 alpha">
  <h2>Keep me informed about product offers and latest news...</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_8 omega">
  <div class="block">

  <p class="search">

  <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="signup text" ValidationGroup="es" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email address" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ValidationGroup="es" TabIndex="2"/>
  <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="rfvEmail" HighlightCssClass="testVal" />
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address" ValidationExpression="<%$AppSettings:regExEmail%>" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None"  ValidationGroup="es" TabIndex="3"/>
   <cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vceEmail" runat="server" TargetControlID="rgEmail" HighlightCssClass="testVal" /> 

    <asp:Button ID="BtnSignUp" runat="server" Text="Go >" CssClass="button blue" TabIndex="2" ValidationGroup="es" />

    </p>

  </div>
  </div>

  </asp:Panel>
```

The following is where the errors are coming from:

```
 Partial Class userControls_emailSignUp
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        txtEmail.Attributes.Add("value", "Your Email Address")
        txtEmail.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "javascript:this.value='';")
    End If

    If Request.QueryString("emailSignUp") = "True" Then
        PanelSignUp.Visible = False
        PanelThankYou.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I have also tried adding a new textbox on the form but can't access that either in the code behind.

Comment: and the error messages are...

Comment: 'txtEmail' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection

Comment: I guess perhaps the issue is lying with this line "Inherits="Articulate.userControls_emailSignUp" in the mark up. I don't have any other web project in the solution with the  name "Articulate" Do I need to create this project and move the use controls into that project and only reference the dll of this project

Comment: Articulate should be the name of the namespace. It sounds like your two files are referring to different namespaces. How did you create the file in the first place?